# Сортировать связанные списки

Tags: python

Три списка `a = [Car, Apple, Glass, Table]` и `b = [0.12, 123, 5, 11411]` и `с = [0.8, 42, 0.46, 55]`
Значения второго/третьего списка равны значениям из первого. Как отсортировать список **а** по алфавиту, чтобы значения **b** и **с** сохранили соответствие и тоже отсортировались.

Результат:

```
a = [Apple, Car, Glass, Table]
b = [123, 0.12, 5, 11411]
с = [42, 0.8, 0.46, 55]
```

Comment: "Значения второго/третьего списка равны значениям из первого." -?  Вещественное число не может быть равно строковой переменной. Перефразируйте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выглядит шаманством, но основное тут - использование `zip` и сортировка с ключом. Ну и ещё пришлось кортежи обратно в списки превращать после `zip(*`:

```py
a = ['Car', 'Apple', 'Glass', 'Table']
b = [0.12, 123, 5, 11411]
c = [0.8, 42, 0.46, 55]
abc = sorted(zip(a, b, c), key=lambda x: x[0])
a, b, c = list(map(list, zip(*abc)))
print(a, b, c, sep='\n')
```

Вывод:

```
['Apple', 'Car', 'Glass', 'Table']
[123, 0.12, 5, 11411]
[42, 0.8, 0.46, 55]
```